# Regularity of language with finite number of right derivatives

Tags: fl.formal-languages

I found this statement listed as a theorem in a textbook:

> If L ⊆ Σ∗ is any language, then L is regular iff it has finitely many right derivatives. Furthermore, if L is regular, then all its right derivatives are regular and their number is equal to the number of states of the minimal DFA’s for L.*

Unfortunately, no proof was provided. Why is this statement true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Janusz Brzozowski's 1964 paper [*Derivatives of Regular Expressions*](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=321249). This is theorem 5.2 in the paper, and the proof is in Appendix 2.